# Where's the location of installed lldb in macOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a plugin name "C/C++ for Visual Studio Code", and it will install lldb, which the path of lldb installed in macOS now?

Comment: `which lldb` in terminal yields `/usr/bin/lldb`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [`LLDB_FRAMEWORK_INSTALL_DIR` is set to `Library/Frameworks`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/39c65fb3ea6ddbec92b32efa1a7fbd0fb299ce63/cmake/modules/LLDBConfig.cmake#L326) for its Makefile, have a look at `/Library/Frameworks`.

That should be the default installation folder.